# Need help with hashTable

Tags: java, hashtable

I have coded something which would return the contents of a excel sheet as a hashTable. The code is

```
    public Object[][] validDataProviderScenarioOne() {
      excelWorker excel = new excelWorker();
      String pathValue = excelWorker.LocatingXls("Data.xls");
      Hashtable<String, String>[] hashDrv =(Hashtable<String, String>[]) excel.contentReading(pathValue, "xxxxx_Login"); 
      Object[][] obj = new Object[hashDrv.length][1];
      for(int i=0; i<hashDrv.length; i++) {
       obj[i][0] = hashDrv[i];
      }
      return obj;
   }
```

now, if there are 3 rows in excel sheet it will have 3 sets of data in it. now what i want is, i want to add some data in the hashtable for each entry in the hashtable array

For eg :
the contents of the sheet

User No userName password

```
1 xxxxxx yyyyy
2 aaaaaa bbbbb
3 cccccc ddddd
```

now in the hashTable i would like to add key as browser and value as *iexplore,*mozilla,*safari, but i dont want to add this in the excel sheet.

so my hasHtable will look like

```
userNo=1,userName=xxxxx,password=yyyyy,browser=*iexplore
userNo=1,userName=xxxxx,password=yyyyy,browser=*mozilla
userNo=1,userName=xxxxx,password=yyyyy,browser=*safari
userNo=2,userName=aaaaaa,password=bbbbb,browser=*iexplore
userNo=2,userName=aaaaaa,password=bbbbb,browser=*mozilla
userNo=2,userName=aaaaaa,password=bbbbb,browser=*safari
userNo=3,userName=cccccc,password=ddddd,browser=*iexplore
userNo=3,userName=cccccc,password=ddddd,browser=*mozilla
userNo=3,userName=cccccc,password=ddddd,browser=*safari
```

plz help, thanx in advance

Comment: create a class containing all these fields

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is create a class that contains the fields you want, e.g

```
class User {
    private int id;
    private String username;
    ...
}
```

and return an array (or a Collection) of those.

Incidentally, why are you allocating and returning a two-dimensional array when the second dimension is hard-coded to one element? Why not just return a one-dimensional array?

Comment: Its because am using TestNG Dataprovider option it accepts only two dimensional array